# Select nav tab with jQuery based on id

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a simple nav menu:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" id="home_menu">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="purchase.php"  class="selected" id="information_menu">Information</a></li>
<li><a href="purchase.php" id="contact_menu">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to set the correct menu item to be selected. Some of the menus will have sub menus so I don't think I want to do it by it's URL, so I have set a meta data tag in each page with the correct tabs' id:

```
<meta name="selected_nav_tab" content="home" />
```

Then get the id via jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//set appropriate nav menu to selected
$('#nav li a').removeClass('selected');

//determine which tab should be selected
var selected_tab = $('meta[name=selected_nav_tab]').attr("content");
});
```

How can I use that id("var selected_tab") to select the home tab?

something like:

```
$(#selected_tab).addClass('selected');
```

Probably a no brainer...

Thank you for bailing me out of my head again,

Todd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your html code

you can try if '_menu' always present there.

```
$('#' + selected_tab +'_menu').addClass('selected');
```

or  if you want to select to check its content.

```
$('#nav li a').contains(selected_tab).addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Very nice...thank you. I didn't know you could form selectors like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#' + selected_tab + '_menu').addClass('selected');
```

Your variable `selected_tab` only contains `home` or something else, but your `id` are like `home_menu` and so on and `#` is needed for `id` selector.

So the correct selector would look `#home_menu` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set the selected tab option. You will first have to get the index of the tab you want to select though.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected

```
// Get jQuery object of the tabs element (assuming #nav is where you use the tabs plugin on)
var $tabs = $('#nav');

// Get selected tab id (this is the id right?)
var selected_tab = $('meta[name=selected_nav_tab]').attr('content');

// Get the index of the tab we are going to select
var selected_index = $tabs.find('li').index($tabs.find('li#' + selected_tab));

// Select the tab
$tabs.tabs('option', 'selected', selected_index);
```